# Angular Interview Question - What if a "this" switch was a component how would you design it?

Tags: angular, design-patterns, angular-components

So I was asked this question on an interview and apparently I didn't give enough detail/concepts into the answer, so I'd be interested to hear what I may have missed and to help others with such questions.

**The Question**

If you were to design a component for a wall switch(I.e one that turns on a light), how would you design it and what do you believe the fundamental aspects would be that would make up the component?

**My Answer**

- So I noted that an @Input property to control the initial starting state of the component off/on in this case.
- Internal logic to handle that input event being changed, and then emitting said event out into another component, a light component in this case to trigger the light turning on.
- Perhaps taking a config object as well to determine extra functionality, depending on how complex you need this component to be.
- Having input or attribute selectors to style the component.

What big concepts may have I of missed?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, This question has very broad spectrum answer, and we can not said which one is right and wrong. But, basic design of component you need to consider `single-responsibility` approach. and component re-usability is there.

**First,** design single Switch-component, then You can wrap it into the parent board component. So that every state management must be handle by parent component only. Your child-switch component is responsible only to display status.

- We have Two main approach here to communicate between parent-child component.

  ```
  1. Using `@Input()` and `@Ouput()` decorator
  2. Using Declarative way to do component communication using `rxjs` `behaviour-subject`.
  ```
- we can use `content projection` here with the use of `template-ref` and `ng-template`. This approach is useful when we want to  render dirrent template for dirrent design consideration Thus, we can achieve Polymorephism [*by term only*], so that one single switch-component is re-usable with different styles consideration.
- We can also use Reactive-Forms approach by implementing custom `ControlValueAccesor` so that we can handle toggle of switch from on or off custom-way. By Reactive forms-way we can also leverage async validation rules, and we can also makes `forms-array` and add or removing new switch to board component becomes lot easier. This approach is very useful when you want to use `ATOMIC Design` into consideration.
- We can also use custom `Attribute-Directive`, the same way `Angular/Material` uses by turning simple `input component to mat-input` and same way `button to in ma-raised-button` component. so that we can leverage extend-ability.